reading csv file with inherited classes
datatype,firstname,lastname,identifier,height,weight,email,hiredate,jobposition,salary,nameschool,graduationyear,major,schoolarship
employee,dawid,kowal,919e,185,54,dawid@op.pl,2000-24-05,software,5000
student,mietek,januszewski,43534,143,65,null,null,null,podstawowa,2005,infa,500

how to read file like this ?
public class Person {}

public class Employee extends Person{}

method must be resistant to modification , we must read all type which inherited after person
Can I store this CSV FILE TO this class ?
public class CreatePersonCommand {
    private String dataType;
    private Map<String, String> params;
}


So what's your question? How to read a CSV file? How to create the class? Or how to populate the class with the data from the CSV file?

how to read CSV like this and store it to database if column type in CSV = type of class

Learn to format your code when posting here. I cleaned up some of it for you this time.

As you read each line, test that first field. Branch by each of your possible sub-types: Student, Employee, etc.
The branching would likely best by done by using switch expressions. Or you could use a cascade of if - else.
Collection< Person > persons = new ArrayList<>() ;

… // For each row of CSV
persons.add(
    switch ( datatype ) {
        case "employee" -> return new Employee( … ) ;
        case "student" -> return new Student( … ) ;
        default throw new IllegalStateException( … ) ;
    }
)

To read and parse the CSV, use any of the several good libraries available in the Java ecosystem. My usual choice is Apache Commons CSV, but shop around for your choice.

By the way, Person should probably be interface or abstract rather than class.

this solution is not good - I knew solution like this , every time when I add new type of class I need modify this .
